# How can I dynamically access a page control in a visual basic asp web page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, variables, dynamic, pagecontrol

I am trying to update the text property of multiple labels on my page that I know exist by the naming convention I have below. However when I try to access them in this way I always get an "Input String was not in correct format" error.

```
 For i = 1 To 5
        Dim title As Label = CType(Me.Controls("title" & i), Label)
        title.Text = alist(i * section).inDate
        Dim postDate As Label = CType(Me.Controls("postDate" & i), Label)
        postDate.Text = alist(i * section).inDate
        Dim depart As Label = CType(Me.Controls("depart" & i), Label)
        depart.Text = alist(i * section).department
        Dim mess As Label = CType(Me.Controls("mess" & i), Label)
        mess.Text = alist(i * section).message

    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your line 3 it should be:

```
title.Text = alist(i * section).title
```

I don't know if this causes the problem you described